# How to receive new messages from a telegram channel in a telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, channel

I just want my bot receives a specific channel messages like when a telegram user joins a telegram channel. 
1. I am not Channel creator or admin.
2. I don't want to make my bot, channel admin.
3. I don't want request each channel admin to add my bot to channel members.

**Do you know a way make a bot, join a channel through telegram client UI or API?**

**Is there another way that a bot can receive updates of channel?**

Comment: In Bot API, I can catch chat_id of a channel by its username, but there is no way to get updates of a chat in a bot when bot is not member of chat!

Comment: In Bot API 2.3 said _"Your bot will now get updates about posts in channels. Added new fields channel_post and edited_channel_post to Update"_

I expect this is not restricted to bot that are channel admin.

Answer (score 0):

Bots cannot join groups or start conversations with a user by themselves as is stated in the [Bot introduction page](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans):

> Bots can't initiate conversations with users. **A user must either add them to a group or send them a message first.** People can use *telegram.me/* links or username search to find your bot.

I am not 100% sure if this also applies for channels, however, I don't seem to see anything that indicates that it doesn't apply.

There may be another way to do what you want, but not utilising the Bot-API.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/vysheng/tgl

Bot, by definition, can't get messages from channels/groups/chats which it doesn't member of

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know a way make a bot, join a channel through telegram client UI or API?

Bots can not join channels as members.

All bots in channel should be admin.

So only the creator of channel can add bots.

Comment: There are some commercial bot that redirect message from a (not mine) channel to a my own channel....how they works?